# How to remove personal data from PS3?

Tags: ps3, psn

I've decided to get rid of my PS3 by donating it to a younger brother. This means that I want to totally purge all data on it such as user accounts, save games, credit card details and the like before I give it to them. (I love my little brothers but they aren't getting my credit card number or owt). Is this possible? Does Settings > System Settings > Restore PS3 System option actually do this?

I did look for other questions before posting this one but they all seemed to be about removing user accounts and not the whole thing.

Comment: Make sure that browser history is cleared ;)

Comment: ...I would be __really__ worried if that had owt to do with my credit cards.

Comment: Restore PS3 system should wipe it all, do that then double check to see if any accounts are left? There really shouldn't be

Comment: I'm sure there's a Format Drive option in the system settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PS3 can reformat its hard drive. Reformatting the hard drive will erase everything on it except system software which you need. You don't need any special hardware for this- just the console, the hard drive and time.

The format utility is found in settings-> system settings. From there, follow the on-screen instructions.

Comment: This is it. You also have to deactivate your PSN account first by going to PSN > Account Management > System Activation. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

1. Scroll to the left to settings
2. Scroll up to system settings
3. Scroll down to restore PS3 system